# Is it possible to make iOS Calendar alerts selectively make noise while in silent mode?

Tags: ios, calendar, alarm, productivity

I usually leave my cell phone on silent mode.

The only thing that breaks the silence are the alarms.

Ideally I'd be able to selectively set some, or all, calendar alerts to make noise in silent mode.

I’m always afraid I’ll miss the alerts, so I sometimes add alarms as well, but they aren’t a great solution.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 yes. I'd even be happy to make all calendar alerts make an audible noise. I usually have my phone right next to me, but often times miss calendar alerts. Same with Reminders App.